# Can someone explain the strange result of "set" in Bash Shell, please?

Tags: environment-variables

When I type the command "set" in a Bash terminal window on my Linux Fedora 12 set up, I get the expected 105 lines of Environment Variables, then the line "_ImageMagick" followed by 9170 lines of program code starting with:

```
{ 
    local prev;
    prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]};
    case "$prev" in 
        -channel)
            COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W 'Red Green Blue Opacity \
            Matte Cyan Magenta Yellow Black' -- "$cur" ));
        return 0
```

... and ending with:

```
set_prefix () 
{ 
    [ -z ${prefix:-} ] || prefix=${cur%/*}/;
    [ -r ${prefix:-}CVS/Entries ] || prefix=""
}
```

Can anyone explain what this is all about, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set command lists not only shell variables but also shell functions. Use env if you want only variables.

Comment: Thank you Radix, nicely explained.

Comment: You are most welcome! I had the same issue with other shell functions and when it first occurred, it was a big surprise to me. Glad I could help.